# Infinite Loop in Lookup Function in Hash Table Implementation

Tags: python, algorithm, hashtable

The code below is meant to demonstrate the principle of linear probing in a hash table. In the lookup function, if an item is not present, an infinite loop is entered. I can see why - the function keeps "wrapping around" to the start of the hashtable. I think the correct logic would be to keep track of where the search started (the hash of the key being searched for), and exit if this position is reached again. Does this sound reasonable? What would my code look like if this change were implemented? Also if there are any other errors in the code I would be grateful to know.

```
TABLE_SIZE = 5

contacts = [
    ("Sam", 1234),
    ("Steve", 5678),
    ("Joseph", 9101),
    ("Peter", 2134),
    ("Jo", 1516),
    ("Anouk", 1718),
]


def my_hash_function(key):
    return len(key) % TABLE_SIZE


def insert(contact, hash_table):
    if None not in hash_table:
        print("Hash table is full.")
        return
    index = my_hash_function(contact[0])  # contact[0] is the key.
    print(f"Hash value of key is {index}")
    while hash_table[index] is not None:
        index += 1
        if index >= TABLE_SIZE:
            index = 0
    print(f"Inserting {contact} at index {index}.")
    hash_table[index] = contact


def lookup(search_key, hash_table):
    index = my_hash_function(search_key)
    while hash_table[index] and hash_table[index][0] != search_key:
        index += 1
        if index >= TABLE_SIZE:
            index = 0
    if hash_table[index] is not None:
        return hash_table[index]


my_hash_table = [None] * TABLE_SIZE

# Add some contacts
for contact in contacts:
    insert(contact, my_hash_table)
    print(my_hash_table)
    # input("Press Enter to continue.")
    print()

print("Search results:")
print(lookup("Pam", my_hash_table)) # Bad program!
print(lookup("Pankaj", my_hash_table))
print(lookup("Jo", my_hash_table))
```

Answer (score 0):

There's room for other improvements but to answer your question you could change your lookup function as follows:

```
def lookup(search_key, hash_table):
    index = my_hash_function(search_key)
    mark = index
    while hash_table[index] and hash_table[index][0] != search_key:
        index += 1
        if index >= TABLE_SIZE:
            index = 0
        if index == mark:
            return None
    if hash_table[index] is not None:
        return hash_table[index]
```

Comment: That's great. Thanks. Would you be willing to point out the other flaws?

Comment: I appreciate that your work is experimental but this is Python and you're essentially re-inventing the wheel. This is why Python has dictionaries

Comment: Of course dictionaries would be the way to go in production code, but I'm trying to illustrate how hash tables work "under the hood" at a concept level. It would be good to have a separate chaining version too, which would store multiple entries in separate lists if needed. Maybe I'll implement both and submit to code review stack exchange. Is there anything obvious that needs fixing before I do?